# Why do I see '?' instead of error output?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I am running my QT project and see compiler output like this

> note:  ??. ?????????? "LoginForm"

I want to see english or russian text instead of '?' signgs.
How to fix the wrong format?

Project folder is fine:  `C:\dev\projects_name`

Also I was trying to chane  (Edit -> Preferences -> Environment -> Language) -- I was trying English, Russia and System language but it didn't help

I am using QT on Windows 10 and Desktop Qt 6.6.2 MSVC2019 64bit

I mean output like this
[image]

Comment: compiler output or do you mean console output? Might be a problem with terminal not able to render UTF-8

Comment: You should show what actual command you are using to print and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Wild guess: you are printing Cyrillic UTF16 text as 8 bit text without conversion, or you are converting Cyrilic to Latin1 or terminal doesn't support Cyrillic characters.

Comment: That is compiler output? Very weird.

Comment: Attached output

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to change Visual Studion compiler language

My actions

1. Open Visual Studio installer
2. Download English language pack

Comment: that option is available  only if you have English installed on Windows.  Or if you're not airgapped. Belive me, I've ran in situation where it wasn't installed in OS and then you can't install lang pack for VS. But there is a trick -  some MS compilers will ouput in Win-1251 only, while Creator supports now ONLY Unicode and can force newer MS compilers to Unicode as well, they use an environment variable `VSLANG` and can fallback to english if `VSLANG=1033`.

Answer (score 1):

> Also I was trying to change (Edit -> Preferences -> Environment -> Language)

You also have the "[View Output](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-how-to-view-output.html)":

> ### Change text encoding
>
> If the text in the output is not displayed correctly, Qt Creator might be using a different codec from the one used by the tools that generate the output.
>
> To specify the codec to use, select [Preferences](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-how-to-find-preferences.html) `> Environment > Interface`, and then select the codec in the Text codec for tools field.
>
> [image]

Comment: What codec should I use for Windows? I was trying codec "UTF-8" and English language
But it didn't work

Comment: @mascai Did you try [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)?

Comment: Win 1252 didn't help

Comment: @mascai How about Windows-1251 (for Cyrillic script)? Or ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1), or ISO 8859-5 (Cyrillic)?

Answer (score 1):

For old Visual Studio or Qt Creator set environment variable `VSLANG=1033` (or other latin1 language  you want, 1033 switches to English). Newer Qt Creator and VS after 2019 support Unicode and there is setting to Force Unicode in Visual Studio Kit's parameters.